# MYSQL is automatically decrypting my password upon record entry

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I have a script that adds an email address and password to a table. I first search to see if the email address exists in the table. If it does, I give an error message. If it does not, I add the record.

Then, using mysqli_insert_id(), I run another query to update the record I just added, encrypting the password with md5.

But every time I run it, the record is added, but the password does not get updated with the md5 version of the password. I have echo'd the query and it shows that it should be updating the password with the encryption, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "eits_Admin", "WebSpinner1", "EITS_Sandbox");
    if (!$link) {
        die("Database connection error");
    }
    $error = '';
    if (!$_POST['email']) {
        $error .= "<br/>An email address is required";
    }
    if (!$_POST['password']) {
        $error .= "<br/>A password is required";
    }   
    if ($error != "") {
        $error = "There were errors in your form - ".$error;
    } else {
        $query = "select id from secretdiary 
                  where email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])
                ."' limit 1";
        // echo $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $error = "That email address is not available.";
        } else {
            $query = "insert into secretdiary 
                                (email,password) 
                      values ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']) 
                        . "', '" 
                        . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']) . "')";

            if (!mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                $error = "Could not sign you up at this time. Please try again later.";
            } else {
                $encPass = md5(md5(mysqli_insert_id($link)) . $_POST['password']);
                $query = "update secretdiary 
                            set password = '" . $encPass 
                        . "' where id = " . mysqli_insert_id($link) . " limit 1";
                echo $query;
                $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
                echo "Sign up successful.";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<div id="error"><? echo $error; ?></div>
<form method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder= "Your Email">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value=1>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!">
</form>
```

Comment: the first INSERT will be unencrypted (actually, un-_hashed_ , you're not _encrypting_ anything - it pays to understand the difference). It won't be converted to the hashed version until the UPDATE command runs. If you think the UPDATE is failing, then check for an error - you don't do anything with the `$result` that comes back from that query.

Comment: However I can't understand why you don't just add the hashing the first time when you INSERT? There seems to be no point in doing it separately. What was the reason for that? I see you're using the generated ID in the hash, but you could just as well use any random value, as long as you know what it is. In fact, I'd argue using the ID is a _bad_ idea since it's very discoverable and could potentially be used easily to try and break the hash.

Comment: And lastly, md5 is no longer secure really - hardware is powerful enough to brute force it. Double-hashing might help a bit but it would be better just to use PHP's recommended [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) functionality.

Comment: And a bit of sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Sorry one more thing, it would also make your SQL a lot more readable (and a tiny bit more secure, and somewhat less prone to unexpected syntax errors) to start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: Also your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @BarryBeach The code below does exactly what you need. Simply Answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of lines of code for a relatively simple process. Personally your form error handling such as if it's empty (in this case) can be remedied by adding `required` at the end of each HTML form input element (This is what I'd do)

Secondly, md5 isn't safe for hashing passwords (you're hashing a password not encrypting it)

Thirdly here's a way to hash the password from the form using Bcrypt which is much better than using md5 hashing. So do whatever error checking you need to do before `like counting the usernames and if row > 0 die('username exists)` Example of full code at base using PDO

When checking the users login simply use `password_verify()` function to do so

Tidy code helps people on SO understand what your problem is and is generally nicer to read. I know you may just be looking for something that '*Does the job*' But it helps you when debugging and us when you're asking for help.

I'm going to give you a way that is marginally more secure than your one.

index.php

```
    <form method="post" id="regform" action="register.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your email    Address"required/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required/>
    <input type="submit" class="indexbttn" id="indexbttn" name="enter"value="enter"/>
</form>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$dbname = "fyp";
try{
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,   $dbpassword);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print "Error! Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
```

register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('connect.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

 if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
  $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
  $pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;
  $check (!filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));

  $cnt = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($cnt);
  $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if($row['num'] > 0){
      die('That username already exists!');
  }
  $passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
  $insrt = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($insrt);
  $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passHash);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  if($result){
    header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
echo 'You will be redirected in  5 seconds. If not, click <a       href="index.php">here</a>.';
  }
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
require("connect.php");
  if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) :   null;
 $pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;
$rtrv = "SELECT username, password, userid FROM users WHERE username =       :username";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($rtrv);
  //Bind value.
  $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
  //Execute.
  $stmt->execute();
  //Fetch row.
   $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  //If $row is FALSE.
  if($user === false){
  //Could not find a user with that username!
  die('Incorrect username');
  }
  else{
      $validPassword = password_verify($pass, $user['password']);
    if($validPassword){
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();
        header( "Location: /protected.php" );
        die();
      } else{
          die('Wrong password!');
    }
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Okay, sorry if I'm going to offend you by saying this, but that's a poor part of the course if it's still using escaping strings and md5 hashes... both extremely dangerous code to expose anyone to nowadays. I  would strongly recommend you achieve this in a less archaic manner..

Comment: @BarryBeach Why are you getting offended? If you knew the code was already bad and it was something you were copying from Udemy, you should have been more clear in your question what you were asking.

Comment: @BarryBeach, MD5 was never a standard for passwords. Ever. It's sadly just a really bad habbit of PHP developers. I urge you to consider looking for a better course. It seems to teach really bad practices. Absence of parameterized queries is another one, for instance.